# Trouble opening large OBJ with VTK

Tags: python, vtk

I'm trying to open a relatively large OBJ file (16mb) using VTK (https://www.vtk.org/) but python keeps crashing (becomes unresponsive, no error messages). I've tried loading a smaller obj (Utah teapot, 51kb) with no issue.

I know that my OBJ file is valid as it will load just fine in commercial software like Meshlab.

Is there any way to get error messages to help debug the problem? The code I have is trivial but it's failing specifically at the `reader.Update()` line.

```
reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()
reader.SetFileName(fileName)
reader.Update()
poly_data = reader.GetOutput()
```

Comment: Can you give the number of cells / vertices of your data set ? Does it fit in an int ?

Comment: [this file](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/IO/Geometry/vtkOBJReader.cxx) tells you how you file should be formatted. You can check if you large file is compliant.

Comment: The obj file is about 590,000 lines long. Although I can't verify that the file has the proper format, a cursory scan seems to have the right formatting, and it does open in other software (meshlab) so I would assume it's the correct formatting.

Comment: I open OBJ files of size exceeding 100 MB using the vtkOBJReader. I use C++, but this should not matter, as VTK/Python is just a wrapper. There might be an issue with the obj format, which can be handled by Meshlab but not vtk. Any chance that we can have a look at the file?